# Eclipse update manager

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I followed the following link's help to install plugin to eclipse.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/updatesite/help?url=http%3A//download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/

They have said that " Add a new site using the url http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/ to the Eclipse Update Manager. "

where is Eclipse Update Manager? how to add site for this?

Please help me... I am struggling here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find the update manger with the help button in eclipse.
in the upcoming menu is the update manager (install new software).

Comment: help -> install new software -> with add you can define the link of the update site

Comment: There are 2 links one starts with download/..... other one is with user/<>/p2/repo    which one should be added? both... ? If so where?

Comment: but it gives error as follows:    couldn't find http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds

Comment: it should work, i have tested the link...(put the link in the field with the http://) maybe you messed up the link, or a typing error?

Comment: I put that one. Did you try recently? When I open this in browser, it gave not found!

Comment: I tried it three ours ago....it should work. It doesnt work in a Browser but inside eclipse it should work. The link shoul look like http:\\download....  Maybe you messed up with the http or spelling oft the link?

Comment: Error is as follows:                                            Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/content.xml.
Failure initializing default SSL context

Comment: It couldn't load eclipse marketplace. The progress bar remains in the same place for hours even though there is firm internet connection...

Comment: I download jar files with the correct directory order... how to install it?