# I'm trying to install Aptana Studio and I get an info 1625 error

Tags: aptana, windows-server-2012

I am trying to install Aptana Studio on the following

- Windows Server 2012 64 bit
- IIS 7

When I go through the install, I get an error of info `1625. This installation is forbidden by system policy`.

I have full admin rights on that machine and the system administrator also tried to install it with the same results.

I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Talk to whoever sets the group policies for your computer. Someone has created a system policy setting that's not letting the installation happen.

Comment: Did you try installing using the right-click "_as administrator_" (I suppose that you're talking about the stand-alone installation)? For example, the [Eclipse plugin manager works this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458873/) to allow updates.